# The singleton class has different assigned addresses

Tags: python, singleton

In the a.py class, it's fetching values for the indicators dictionary. I'm trying to save those values to a global dictionary variable in container.py and then access them in b.py.

So, I declared a singleton called GlobalContainer in container.py and declared a dictionary inside it. Then, in a.py, I added the values fetched to that dictionary. However, when I tried to access the dictionary in the singleton from b.py, there were no values. Upon checking, I found that the memory address of GlobalContainer in container.py is different.

I need a single data storage accessible from a.py, b.py, c.py, etc. I don't understand why the singleton addresses are different.

container.py

```
class Singleton:
  def __init__(self, decorated):
    self._decorated = decorated
    self._initialized = False  # Flag for first instance creation

  def instance(self):
    if not self._initialized:
      self._instance = self._decorated()
      self._initialized = True
    return self._instance

  def __call__(self):
    raise TypeError('Singletons must be accessed through `instance()`.')

  def __instancecheck__(self, inst):
    return isinstance(inst, self._decorated)

  def __wrap__(self, instance, objtype, wrapper):
    # Allow access to class methods using the actual class object (cls)
    instance.__getattribute__ = lambda self, name: getattr(objtype, name, self.__dict__[name])
    return wrapper(instance)

@Singleton
class GlobalContainer:
    containers = {}

    def __init__(self):
    # No initialization check needed here
        print("### GlobalContainer created")  # This will print only once

    @classmethod
    def set_indicators(cls, symbol, indicators):
        if symbol not in cls.containers:
            cls.containers[symbol] = {'indicators': indicators}
        else:
            cls.containers[symbol]['indicators'] = indicators

    @classmethod
    def get_indicators(cls, symbol):
        container = cls.containers.get(symbol, {})
        return container.get('indicators', None)
```

in a.py

```
GlobalContainer.instance().set_indicators(self.symbol, self.indicators)
```

in b.py

```
GlobalContainer.instance().get_indicators(symbol)
```

The print('### GlobalContainer created') in the singleton's init part is executed twice. I want only one instance to be created and used as a global variable for GlobalContainer.

Comment: Are you *required* to implement the singleton pattern like this? If not, [I wouldn't bother](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. Please update your question with a minimal example.

Comment: @chepner I've seen a lot of negative reviews about singletons, but in my situation, it seems like the best option...

Comment: @quamrana okay. I'll simplify and reproduce the scenario shortly, then I'll repost the code. However, what I'm curious about is, theoretically, should the singleton be allocated in the same memory in that situation?

Comment: If its a singleton, then there will only be one instance.

Comment: Best option for *what*, exactly? If you only want one instance, then don't call `GlobalContainer` more than once. (Or don't call it *at all*; let a separate factory function return a single global instance, creating it if necessary.)  This decorator, in particular, is more like a tiny pebble on the road rather than an actual barrier; if I really want a second instance, I'll just write `g2 = GlobalContainer._decorated()`, and all your supposed safeguards are bypassed in an instance.

Comment: I'm not saying other conventions for singleton instances don't have ways around them, either, but they also are a lot simpler to implement.

Comment: @chepner umm, in a.py, I'm handling socket_message in a function called Foo_a, where I execute a function called get_indicators. If 10 socket_messages come in as callbacks, I store 10 indicators in a local dictionary in a.py. 
Once this processing is done, I want to use these values in the Foo_b function in b.py. At this point, Foo_b is executed through a thread. (Even when I called Foo_b without running a thread, the address of the singleton was different.)

Comment: Are `a.py` and `b.py` separate scripts? Are you expecting two entirely separate processes to share a single object?

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure if a.py and b.py are in different processes even though they are separate scripts. In a.py, there seems to be a keyword 'stream', and it appears to handle data from that stream. I want to store the processed data in a global container and access it from b.py. Is this fundamentally impossible? I'm not very familiar with concepts like threading..

Comment: If you are executing them with separate commands `python a.py` and `python b.py`, they are absolutely separate processes. There is no keyword `stream` in Python.  What you are trying to do has nothing to do with the singleton pattern; you need to research interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

The "singleton" has two different addresses because you are executing two different scripts, each of which defines a new `GlobalContainers` class on start-up. The class is *not* shared between two separate processes.

Comment: Umm,, When it comes to projects created with Visual Studio, multiple scripts within the same project are handled within a single process. However, in Python, even if they are in the same folder, if they are separated into a.py, b.py, c.py, etc., each is considered a separate process? Does that mean in Python, all processing must be done within a single .py file?

Comment: Yes. Either you are confusing "project" with "process", or Visual Studio is doing something highly irregular.